# Laravel - How to give multiple role to an user ?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, laravel

I'm working on a project in Laravel for learning the framework.

I create a basic register/login and after that I customize the register part. 
What am I planning to achieve is the point where an user can act in multiple roles.

For example: 
**user1** can be normal user and administrator(with special access to the application) at the same time.

How should I design this from database point of view ?

Comment: you should try something first, fail doing it, show it to us, then we will help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't create another "user" type entity for companies, but add another table for company data and connect it to a `user`. That way you are able to keep the default registration and login process.

If you wanted a slightly different form to register companies, I'd add another route & form to gather the "user" information as well as "company" information (company name, phone, fax, etc). Then when the registration is processed you can create the `user` entity, along with the `company` relationship with the given information.

However, if you still wanted to create completely different entities with login/registration flows, you'd have to build your own [User Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) and implement the contracts needed.

Comment: Look, I make a default auth, with composer. After that, I clone the users table in the database and rename it. Then I got in my project and make the same files that I need for a user login. But my secound register routes are broke.